# Background-color displaying incorrectly in IE8 and IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I have a megamenu that works perfectly in Chrome, Firefox and IE10. However in versions IE9 and below there is a problem with the background-color property of the menu bar - instead of being a dark gray, it is showing as white. I am using a custom css file to modify the T3v3 framework css file and the bootstrap css file The URL in question is www.minsteadtt.org - it is using the T3v3 framework. The css for the property in question is as follows:

```
.t3-mainnav {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: #676767; 
  border: none;
  font-size: .9em;
}
```

Can anyone explain why the dark gray property is not registering in IE8 and 9?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add `filter: none;` to your t3-mainnav class. That should fix it!

```
.t3-mainnav {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: #676767; 
  border: none;
  font-size: .9em;
  filter: none !important;

}
```

Comment: @nhinkle Because the framework used the filter property to create a gradient for the navbar in IE9 and below, which overwrites the background-color property. You must set filter: none; to get rid of the gradient in IE.

Comment: For most of the times, IE9 tends to add that `filter` property in css object, but you can see that only when you inspect that item with `Inspect element`. You can see there that `filter` property that has to be `none` in most of the cases :) I've discovered this by myself a long time ago, but I got here because I forgot it :)) Nice and easy answer! +1

Answer (score 0):

```
.map-holder{
background:none !important;
filter: none !important;
opacity: 1 !important;
* {
    background:none !important;
    filter: none !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

}

this one helps me with such issue